# Get nearby fire stations to a given location but the results shows medical centers

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API and trying to get nearby fire stations to a given location but the results that I am getting shows medical centers I am sending the request using the following URL and I set the type to "fire+stations" I also tried "fire stations" and "fire departments" but still no success.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.019605,71.5872217&radius=10000&type=fire+station&sensor=true&key={my](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.019605,71.5872217&radius=10000&type=fire+station&sensor=true&key=%7Bmy) paid key}

Comment: ["fire department"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_department)?

Comment: I tried but still showing medical centers

Answer (score 0):

After some detailed research I just found the solution it has to be written as "fire_station" as this is how fire stations are tagged in maps.